# Working with "bed" files in python

Tags: python

I have a .bed file which contains 1000 lines and the words in each line are separated by tab (\t). If we consider each word as one column, each line has 12 columns. 
I need a way to convert this .bed file to a matrix, so that I can access its columns easily.
Foe example, I need to access the column number 12. Is there any way that I can do it?

I already have tried this:

```
    import numpy as np
    data = np.genfromtxt("myFile.bed")
```

but it does not work properly.
Can any one help me please?

Comment: What happens if you use `np.genfromtxt`? Please add details...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BED files are standard tab-delimited text files. Tu usual way to store its content in memory is:

```
content = []
with open("myFile.bed")as f:
    for line in f:
        content.append(line.strip().split())
```

You can either use a numpy array instead of a list here, or transform the result with `np.asarray` if you want.

It is actually rare that you need a matrix from it, since they represent (genomic?) intervals and are often very big. Most of the time you modify/read/execute some function at each line in the loop:

```
with open("myFile.bed")as f:
    for line in f:
        L = line.strip().split()
        # ... do something with L
```

Otherwise, the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library implements "data frames" as in R (but I never used it).

Answer (score 2):

Using [pyranges](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/pyranges), this is as simple as

```
import pyranges as pr

path = pr.get_example_path("aorta.bed")

gr = pr.read_bed(path)
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+
# | Chromosome   | Start     | End       | Name       | Score     | Strand       |
# | (category)   | (int32)   | (int32)   | (object)   | (int64)   | (category)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------|
# | chr1         | 9939      | 10138     | H3K27me3   | 7         | +            |
# | chr1         | 9953      | 10152     | H3K27me3   | 5         | +            |
# | chr1         | 10024     | 10223     | H3K27me3   | 1         | +            |
# | chr1         | 10246     | 10445     | H3K27me3   | 4         | +            |
# | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...        | ...       | ...          |
# | chr1         | 9978      | 10177     | H3K27me3   | 7         | -            |
# | chr1         | 10001     | 10200     | H3K27me3   | 5         | -            |
# | chr1         | 10127     | 10326     | H3K27me3   | 1         | -            |
# | chr1         | 10241     | 10440     | H3K27me3   | 6         | -            |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+
# Stranded PyRanges object has 11 rows and 6 columns from 1 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome and Strand.

df = gr.df
#    Chromosome   Start     End      Name  Score Strand
# 0        chr1    9939   10138  H3K27me3      7      +
# 1        chr1    9953   10152  H3K27me3      5      +
# 2        chr1   10024   10223  H3K27me3      1      +
# 3        chr1   10246   10445  H3K27me3      4      +
# 4        chr1  110246  110445  H3K27me3      1      +
# 5        chr1    9916   10115  H3K27me3      5      -
# 6        chr1    9951   10150  H3K27me3      8      -
# 7        chr1    9978   10177  H3K27me3      7      -
# 8        chr1   10001   10200  H3K27me3      5      -
# 9        chr1   10127   10326  H3K27me3      1      -
# 10       chr1   10241   10440  H3K27me3      6      -
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally had trouble installing [pyranges](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/pyranges).

I used [bed-reader](https://pypi.org/project/bed-reader/), from their examples:

```
from bed_reader import open_bed, sample_file

bed = open_bed("myFile.bed")
val = bed.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another user pointed out that these files are tab delimited, or TSVs. I'm fond of reading these with pandas. Supposing the file is `amplicon.bed`:

```
import pandas as pd

bed = pd.read_csv('amplicon.bed', delimiter='\t')
```